# How to bind data as parameter to ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with ActionLink.
I'd like to pass to my ActionLink parameter for my MessageController, for Edit action: to generate somthing like this /MessagesController/Edit/4

So I have ListView control with binding expression:

and how to pass this ID to ActionLink as parameter to my Controller Edit action?

This doesn't work:
, null) %>

Comment: I don't know why nobody exposed the problem of him using a Container here, what this Container is? I think he is trying to mix ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC somehow, just feels that way. He should have his data in the model. That's why he didn't accept the solution.

Comment: Agreed - if you find yourself coming to this question and doing something similar.. stop.. and pickup an MVC book.. or at least do way more reading about MVC..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("my link", "Edit", "Message", new { id = ((Message)Container.DataItem).ID }) %>
```

You need to put it in the RouteData to get it to show up.  Note I am assuming *id* is one of your route parts that is in your route definition.

Answer (score 6):

In MVC you are not supposed to databind from the view in the way that you have. The data that you want to pass to the ActionLink method needs to be added to ViewData in your controller. Then in the view you retrieve it from ViewData:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("My Edit Link", "Edit", "Message", new { id = ViewData["id"] }) %>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's because it's not in the ViewData but when I do this with an int parameter I get a bad link. The code from below with the additional "null parameter works though. 
<%= Html.ActionLink("text", "action", "controller", new{...}, null) %>

Comment: If you don't provide the null fifth parameter, it's using a different method signature and interpreting the new {...} with parameters as HtmlAttributes instead of as RouteValues. As you say, with the null parameter it should work, since it changes which method it uses.

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("My Edit Link", "Edit", "Message", new { id = ((Message)Container.DataItem).ID }, null) %>
```

Comment: This is the right answer but Container should be replaced with Model or some other ASP.NET MVC construct.